# Python type hint given as a string?

Tags: python, type-hinting

I have a function of this form:

```
def foo(o: "hello") -> dict:
    # pass
```

I understand that the "-> dict" means that foo returns a dictionary. What I don't understand is the "hello" part. Why is this type hint given as a string? What is "hello"?

Possibly relevant - this is an autogenerated file.

Comment: Usually that means that, within the scope of your code, `'hello'` is a type.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

type annotations sometimes need to be set before the object has been created, for example:

```
class Node:
    def next() -> Node:
        pass
```

This piece of code actually fails, because `Node` is referenced as an annotation of `Node.next` while the class `Node` is still being created. This is the same reason why the following fails:

```
class T:
    t = T()
```

To get around this, you can use a string instead

```
class Node:
    def next() -> 'Node':
        pass
```

so the typechecker will only evaluate `Node` later (a [forward reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references)).

---

This was actually [decided](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/) to be a design flaw so in python 3.7 you can use `from __future__ import annotations` and the first example will work.

---

**Edit April 2022**

So a lot has changed (and yet a lot hasn't) since this was made. The most important difference is that string `annotations` was deferred from py 3.10 and it [sounds](https://discuss.python.org/t/type-annotations-pep-649-and-pep-563/11363) like it will never be stabilized. Instead the steering committee will probably end up stabilizing [PEP 649](https://peps.python.org/pep-0649/) instead which has slightly more complex behavior, but still supports self-referential type hints. See the PEP for details.

Comment: What is preferred though (Python 3.9) ?

Comment: It's a bit up in the air. `annotations` were deferred for 3.10. Do whichever you prefer for now.