# Expressing type hint of sibling nested class in class constructor

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

I am using the type hinting system of python when coding with pycharm, which I believe uses the `typing` module, however I have a scenario for which pycharm gives me an error and I can not find an answer on how to make it right online:

```
from typing import List


class Something:
    class A(object):
        def __init__(self, d: int) -> None:
            self.data = d

    class B(object):
        def __init__(self, inListStr: List[str], inListA: List[A]): # "A" here is marked as "Unresolved Reference". Something.A does not fix the issue either
            self.list_of_str = inListStr
            self.list_of_a = inListA

    def __init__(self, inB: B): #B here is accepted ok
        self.data_b = inB
```

Do you know how I can correctly type `inListA` to be of type "list of As"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [from \_\_future\_\_ import annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61544854/from-future-import-annotations) This require python 3.7

Comment: What version of python are you using? I ask because older versions of python didn't have as much flexibility around saying things are of types you're still in the middle of defining (as you're doing here). I don't use pycharm, but for me with python 3.9 and mypy, typehinting with Something.A works fine, even though it doesn't work fine for you.

Comment: @Aaron on python 3.7 and importing annotations from __future__ this works, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `Something.A`, but enclose it in quotes:

```py
...
        def __init__(self, inListStr: List[str], inListA: List['Something.A']):
...
```

The Python interpreter can't evaluate `A` or `Something.A` at that point in the code. By making it a string, the type checker can still figure out the type while avoiding runtime evaluation.

Comment: From what I understand this is not considered to be the "right" thing to do but rather a fallback, see eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51629105/python-type-hint-given-as-a-string . However, it does work if done, and my IDE (PyCharm) picks up the type correctly.