# Python nested classes gives `undefined name`

Tags: python

I've a main class with 2 nested classes:

```py
class cls_1:
  
  class Enum_1(Enum):
     ...
  
  @dataclass
  class Nested:
     ...
     feature: Enum_1 #NameError: name 'Enum_1' is not defined
```

As you can see I'm using one of the nested classes as type in another nested class.
But this gives: `NameError: name 'Enum_1' is not defined` as highlighted in the code.

I feel I'm missing something obvious but not sure what's that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - reference inner class from other inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42185472/python-reference-inner-class-from-other-inner-class)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expressing type hint of sibling nested class in class constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67113582/expressing-type-hint-of-sibling-nested-class-in-class-constructor)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that values defined in the class-definition scope are not available in the inner scopes of that class.

```
class A:
    class B:
        pass
    
    def foo(self):
        print(B) # doesn't work
        print(A.B) # does work
```

For functions this is obvious, as you always need to access class attributes through the instance, but as the code inside a function is an extra scope inside the class another class definition is also an inner scope - where you don't have the names in that are in the outer class defined (hope all that made sense like that...) [See resolution of names in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names)

Well - to solve your problem you need to access the Enum through `cls_1`:

*Edit*: But sadly in that case you have the problem that `cls_1` doesn't exist at that point. So you'd need to set the annotation into quotes so it's not executed. Typecheckers will understand the annotations that way though.

```
class cls_1:
  
  class Enum_1(Enum):
     ...
  
  @dataclass
  class Nested:
     ...
     feature: "cls_1.Enum_1"
```

Comment: There is no `cls_1` by the time the inner class is defined.

Comment: Ah damn - yeah you're right. I've messed up when I was trying it in the interpreter. Well then there's no good solution I guess... :/