# How to define a Pydantic model nested under a class

Tags: python, inner-classes, python-typing, pydantic

I have two Pydantic models:

```py
from typing import List, Union
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Students:
    class Student(BaseModel):
        StudentName: str
        StudentAge: int

    class StudentRequest(BaseModel):
        Class: int
        UUID: str
        Students: Union[List[Student], None]
```

For the above class at `Students: Union[List[Student], None]`, I get the error `Unresolved reference 'Student'`. Can we not define a model under a class and use it for segregating them?

The code below works, but I want to get an understanding whether the above `BaseModel` nested under a class will work or not:

```py
class Student(BaseModel):
    StudentName: str
    StudentAge: int

class StudentRequest(BaseModel):
    Class: int
    UUID: str
    Students: Union[List[Student], None]
```

Comment: I don't think this is strictly related to Pydantic's BaseModel, but a general behavior with nested classes in Python. See: [Python - reference inner class from other inner class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42185472/2745495) and [Expressing type hint of sibling nested class in class constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67113582/2745495)

Comment: how to specify many=True for one of the class? or for all of the classes. I get bool error when I add (many: True) in class

Comment: @Akshitjain can you share the actual example and the error trace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to understand that as long as the outer class is not fully constructed (when you are still setting up things *inside its namespace*), you will inevitably have to deal with [**forward references**](https://peps.python.org/pep-0563/#forward-references).

So there are two mandatory things (and one optional) you need to remember, when doing this.

### 1) Use the qualified class name `OuterClass.InnerClass`

The Python interpreter itself will have no trouble with a forward reference to another inner class in an annotation. That is simply because it does not actually *do* anything with those annotations by default. So you *could* just do this:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class OuterClass:
    class Student(BaseModel):
        name: str
        age: int

    class StudentRequest(BaseModel):
        ...
        students: list["Student"]
```

But this will fall apart with Pydantic models because those actually **use** those annotations to construct objects based off of them. As you will see in the next section, at some point Pydantic will have to actually resolve the refernce to `Student` so get the actual underlying class at runtime. And since that will **inevitably** happen *outside* the scope of the `OuterClass`, without the qualified name, it will run into a `NameError`.

So you have to do it like this:

```py
...

class OuterClass:
    class Student(BaseModel):
        ...

    class StudentRequest(BaseModel):
        ...
        students: list["OuterClass.Student"]
```

### 2) Update forward references after the outer class is constructed

An annotation as shown above is internally stored as a [`ForwardRef`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ForwardRef) object.

As mentioned above, Pydantic will have to resolve those forward references eventually, for you to be able to actually use those models.

However it is [not always able to do so automatically](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/postponed_annotations/). To quote the documentation:

> In some cases, a `ForwardRef` won't be able to be resolved during model creation. [...] When this happens, you'll need to call `update_forward_refs` after the model has been created before it can be used.

But with a setup like yours, when the model is nested in the namespace of an outer class, you cannot just do so after the *model* is created. You must do that after the *outer class* is created.

So with that setup, you will have to do this:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel


class OuterClass:
    class Student(BaseModel):
        name: str
        age: int

    class StudentRequest(BaseModel):
        ...
        students: list["OuterClass.Student"]


OuterClass.StudentRequest.update_forward_refs()
```

Notice that the call happens *outside* of `OuterClass` after it is created.

### 3) Enable postponed evaluation of annotations (optional)

Since [PEP 563](https://peps.python.org/pep-0563/#implementation) you can do `from __future__ import annotations` at the top of your module and then omit the quotes from your forward references. This just improves readability and makes things generally easier to code.

So in total, your code should look like this:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from pydantic import BaseModel


class OuterClass:
    class Student(BaseModel):
        name: str
        age: int

    class StudentRequest(BaseModel):
        ...
        students: list[OuterClass.Student]


OuterClass.StudentRequest.update_forward_refs()
```

**Demo**:

```py
print(OuterClass.StudentRequest.schema_json(indent=4))
obj = OuterClass.StudentRequest.parse_obj({
    "students": [
        {"name": "foo", "age": 18},
        {"name": "bar", "age": 19},
    ]
})
print(obj.json(indent=4))
```

Output:

```json
{
    "title": "StudentRequest",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "students": {
            "title": "Students",
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/Student"
            }
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "students"
    ],
    "definitions": {
        "Student": {
            "title": "Student",
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "title": "Name",
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "age": {
                    "title": "Age",
                    "type": "integer"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "name",
                "age"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

```json
{
    "students": [
        {
            "name": "foo",
            "age": 18
        },
        {
            "name": "bar",
            "age": 19
        }
    ]
}
```