# How should I refactor this parent-child structure?

Tags: python, class, parent-child

i have a system wherein a child object (let's say the object's class name is `BasicObject`) is parented to another object of the same class. the child object has a reference to its parent, but the parent doesn't know anything about the child object.

the parenting info, which dictates how the child behaves from what the parent is doing, is contained in an object of another class (let's say *that* object's class name is `ParentingInfo`)

the catch is that both `BasicObject` and `ParentingInfo` are in separate files with the following restrictions:

- both files are in the same folder
- use relative imports to add a layer of portability for each folder in the project (since these two, along with a few more packages, are in a folder)
- separate `BasicObject` and `ParentingInfo` as well as other objects used by `BasicObject` (like for example, its `RenderInfo` to determine how it is rendered) into separate files to organize further
- parents and children may only use one class, specifically `BasicObject`
- `BasicObject` and `ParentingInfo` should not inherit one another
- type hinting is required

```py
# basic_object_pkg.py =====================================================

from . import parent_info_pkg

class BasicObject():
    """An object used to represent stuff."""
    def __init__(self, ..., parenting_info: parent_info_pkg.ParentingInfo, ...):
        ...
        self.parenting_info = parenting_info
        ...

    ...


# parent_info_pkg.py =====================================================

from . import basic_object_pkg

class ParentingInfo():
    """Contains parenting information of a BasicObject."""
    def __init__(self, parent: basic_object_pkg.BasicObject, ...):
        self.parent = parent
        ...


    ...
```

**How would I go about refactoring this code to:**

- **Not have circular imports; and**
- **Children has references to their parented `BasicObject`s?**

if it's impossible to keep those rules, please let me know with the best possible approach to keep the code as organized as possible

Comment: Why is it a parent-child relation if the parent doesn't even know about the child? Aren't you perhaps mixing up the assignment of parent and child?

Comment: i assumed it was a parent-child relation, but i did not know there were different types of it. could you help me out and give some information about the "assignment of parent and child" thing?

Comment: If you use strings as type hints, this will work around needing any imports. See answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51629105/python-type-hint-given-as-a-string)